# Visual Studio 2010 Express Failed to Create Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I had to uninstall Microsoft Visual 2010 because it wouldn't start and when i got done re-installing it it gives me this. 
Creating Project "Panda" project creation failed.
[link to a picture.](http://gyazo.com/09e2433153ee0372132fc8551f83ed07)
It worked just fine before i uninstalled it and i love vs2010 it kind of part of me now.

I am running on window 7 home premium 64-bit.
I have re-installed it as a admin.(all users on this computer are admins)
Im trying to create a Win32 Console Application.(It dose not matter what type of project i try and make it will give me this error every time)
And it is installed for all users. I'm trying to create it on the Desktop.
I really need help with this i love vs2010 to death.

Comment: An image of the entire screen to show the tiny error message in the lower left corner isn't helpful. You could be a little considerate and crop the image so that the entire thing doesn't have to be retrieved. (Not that the image provides any information you don't have in your test itself, BTW - I'm not sure what the point was of including that link at all.) You need to [edit] and provide more detail; there's no info here to use to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure what else i can add. Do i need to add a log of some sorts ?

Comment: There's nothing here we can use to help. Did you run the installation as an administrator? Did you install for all users of the computer? What user are you using to run the IDE (admin or other)? What folder is it trying to create the project in? What type of project is it? (You can remove "Microsoft" from the subject and tags while you're editing, BTW - there is no other Visual Studio, as it's a MS product, so saying so is redundant.

Comment: All users on this computer are admins. I installed it for all users. I'm trying to create the folder on my desktop. I'm tying to make a Win32 Console Appication.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, as I mentioned before. Burying the additional information in the comments isn't really useful, as people can't see it there without reading them all. Why are you trying to create the project on your *desktop*? VS usually uses a sub-folder of your Documents folder specifically for VS projects, and that location is always writeable by the current user.

Comment: I have always used my desktop for things of this sort so it manly a habit.

Comment: Have you tried creating the project in another location?  Have you tried VS 2012?

Comment: I have tried vs2012 and it was very confusing to me and yes i have tried creating it in a deferment location.

Comment: Should i give vs2012 a there shot?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't create *any* type of project, then it sounds like your installation of Visual Studio is corrupted. A couple of things to try:

1. Open the Visual Studio Command Prompt (or use the regular Command Prompt with an explicit path) and execute the following command to reset all of your settings to factory defaults:

   ```
   devenv /resetsettings
   ```
2. Perform an in-place installation, right on top of the existing installation. That will restore any files that have been deleted or otherwise corrupted since the original installation.

Switching to Visual Studio 2012 as Trevor suggested might work too, for the same reason that it resets all settings to their defaults and reinstalls all of the necessary files. But you certainly don't have to switch if you don't want to. I use VS 2010 every day to create projects. It has no showstopper bug that prevents this. And I couldn't agree more with you about VS 2012 being ugly and confusing.

If reinstalling it doesn't work, then you've got some more serious registry corruption issues that plague your machine. There isn't a good fix for that other than reloading Windows.

Comment: Ok thank you i think i do have a registry problem this computer has allot of other things wrong with it. I have tied ccleaner for registry cleaning and iobits advanced system care but no matter what i do there are some things that still don't work.

Comment: I tied vs 2012 professional and i had tried ultimate before and i must say that i love the professional version allot its simple and not as crazy as ultimate. It was a instant buy.

Comment: devenv is not recognized as an internal command? do i need to set a path?

Comment: Uh, yeah. You either need to use the VS Command Prompt, or you need to give it a path to Visual Studio. Something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\Common\IDE`, but I'm doing that from memory.